# Can we be paid for research papers in any way?

Tags: research-process, research-undergraduate, education

I have written many papers and got them published but the problem is that publishing them takes a lot of money and resources and its not possible for me to continue writing if I am being charged for my own talent. To continue my talent I want some money for the articles that I have already published.

Comment: I suspect that this is an XY-problem type of question. Publishing research papers should not cost the author money, and if you do end up paying, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Arno: In a narrow sense, that is not necessarily true. In some fields where conferences are the primary method of publication, publishing something indeed requires paying the attendance fee for (and travel to) the conference - and independent researchers would have to pay that somehow. Whether there are possibilities to get someone else to pay for such expenses (e.g. by not being an independent researcher any more, but getting formally affiliated with some institution, or by securing some external funding) is indeed a question worth pursuing, though.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper But the question here seems to be about making  money from already published papers, which will usually simply be impossible.

Comment: @Amo Actually in many fields (I am most familiar with biomedical research) it is common for publishing to incur costs to the authors, whether a flat fee or by page, even in very reputable journals.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you are looking for - the traditional methods of being paid to do research is 1) stipend as a grad student, or 2) job as an academic (professor, post doc, government lab, or industry lab). Are you looking for something outside of these options?

Comment: @Bryan Krause My understanding is that in those fields where publication charges are common, there are paid for by the institution or by a grant, not by personal funds from the researcher. If the former are not available, I would expect the fees to be waived.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." -- 'Then don't do it!" /// if publishing isn't of value to you, don't publish, but research papers are not in the business of being monetized. Maybe you can write for a popular (not academic) magazine instead?

Answer (score 1):

I have some publications of my own, 4 to be precise. I don't think I will make any money out of them anytime in future. I don't really think, anyone can make money out of a research paper. If you are really into making money, I think you should go for publishing patents. If you patent something that others find useful(& worth spending money) you could probably get a licensing fee or may be come to some sort of monetary arrangement.